# php syntax to call hana stored procedure

Tags: php, hana

I get a syntax error when calling stored procedure. What I used is:

```
 $sp="call'ZSECURITY'.'xxx.security.core.catalog.procedures/USER_AUTH_PSWD_RESET'('userid','password',?)";

$result = odbc_exec($conn,$sp);
```

Comment: @Rizier123: syntax error

Answer (score 0):

My first idea here is that you're using the wrong quotes inside your SQL statement. Try this instead:

```
$sp='call "ZSECURITY"."xxx.security.core.catalog.procedures/USER_AUTH_PSWD_RESET"(\'userid\',\'password\',?)'; 
$result = odbc_exec($conn,$sp);
```